# Splitting the data of one excel column into two columns sing python

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, split

I have problem of splitting the content of one excel column which contains numbers and letters into two columns the numbers in one column and the letters in the other.

As can you see in the first photo there is no space between the numbers and the letters, but the good thing is the letters are always "ms". I need a method split them as in the second photo.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

I tried to use the replace but it did not work. it did not split them.

Is there any other method.

Comment: `pd.Series.str.split('(ms)$', expand=True)` ?

Comment: Where exactly will be the name of the column?

Comment: sorry but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extract` method. Here is an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['34ms', '239ms', '126ms']})

df[['time', 'unit']] = df['time'].str.extract('(\d+)(\D+)')

# convert time column into integer
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(int)

print(df)

# output:
#     time unit
# 0   343   ms
# 1   239   ms
# 2   126   ms
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. 
You need to use pandas.Series.str.split 
Attaching the Syntax here :- [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

The Code should be

```
import pandas as pd

data_before = {'data' : ['34ms','56ms','2435ms']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_before)

result = df['data'].str.split(pat='(\d+)',expand=True)
result = result.loc[:,[1,2]]
result.rename(columns={1:'number', 2:'string'}, inplace=True)
```

Output : -

```
print(result)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMy0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Excel file with this data in Notepad++, change `ms` for `,ms`, save as `CSV (comma delimited)`. Open with Excel.